# Why pgAdmin copies the existent databases to the new servers?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I use pgAdmin 4. pgAdmin comes with a default server named 'postgreSQL 12'. I created my own server or database cluster, but I found out that all the databases in the old server are copied to the new server created by me. By the way, I used the host name 127.0.0.2 and port 5432. How can I prevent copying the old databases to the new server?. One more thing: What is precisely host name/Address. I get stuck with the host name while creating a new cluster because I`m new to SQL. I appreciate if anyone helps me choose a host name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly did you "create your own server"? Did you run `initdb` to create a second instance on a different port?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the template0, template1 and postgres databases, then they are present in every cluster. If not then you will need to tell us what databases?  Localhost is 127.0.0.1, there is no host 127.0.0.2. So I'm guessing you are looking at your original cluster. Two Postgres clusters cannot run on the same port, so again you are probably only dealing with one cluster. A host can either be an IP address(example:127.0.0.1) or a domain name(some_name.com).

Answer (score 0):

On many systems all things starting with `127.` are just aliases for the same machine, the local machine.  This appears to be the case for you, so you do not have a copy of the database instance, you have one database instance with two ways to spell the connection to it.

In order to create a database on a different host, you first have to *have* a different host.  Do you?  pgAdmin4 does not create database instances (except possibly during installation, if you use the bundled installer), it creates connections to already existing instances.